# Selectors for an element with a specific attribute using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is [Javascript Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFMAF.png) in which I'm trying to add an attr content that says P1 for player 1 and p2 for player. When a character is selected. Where you see $this css it changes the button background after its been selected, but now I trying to add P1 and P2 after the user selects their character. Look at the image I shared, as a visual of what I want to do.

[Result I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyWrb.png)

```
$characters
        .removeClass(oldClass)
        .addClass(newClass)
        .fadeIn('slow');

    $('#charactersname').text(newClass.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newClass.slice(1));

    $this.css('background-color', '#00cc99').attr('P1');

    characterSelect = $('#characters').attr('class');

    document.getElementById('charselect').innerHTML =
            ' You have selected ' + characterSelect.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newClass.slice(1);

    choices.push(characterSelect);
}

function performNextAction(){
    if(choices.length < 2){
        confirm(`Player ${choices.length + 1}, choose your character!`);
        $('.grid-container').one('click', 'img', selectCharacter);
    }
    else{
        choices.forEach((choice, index) => localStorage.setItem(`Player${index + 1}`, choice));

        window.location = 'selectbg.html';
    }
}
```

Comment: Post Complete snippet what is your $this, its incomplete question try to explain in a better way

Comment: I added $this snippet. As of now this is just changing the background of the button when a character is selected. I to add atrr() as a dot notation and inside the brace I put P1 to test it but P1 did not display

Comment: I guess you want to achieve this doing this `<p>P1</p>`, i am considering here $this select paragraph. If you want to do this then You need to use text instead of attr or more formally `$this.css('background-color', '#00cc99').text('P1');`

Comment: The attr method is used to set or get value of any attribute of DOM element https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp Read this for detail, If you want to visualize the P1 then you either need to use this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp

Comment: ok I tried $this.css('background-color', '#00cc99').text('P1'); and $this.css('background-color', '#00cc99').html('<b>Hello world!</b>'); from w3schools and the text of P1 isn't displaying any text above any character that I select. I tried using CSS content: 'P1'. That also didn't display any text any text

Comment: I was doing some researching and the code below work when I initiate the code in the dev tool console. But when I add it to my code and refresh the browser, P1 doesn't appear when I select a character. I also want to do a P2 when Player 2 selects their character 


$(".button").click(function(){
  $("<h2>P1</h2>").appendTo("h2").innerHTML;
});.

Comment: Basically to perform your task its required to see your DOM structure of Your Code as well as Your javascript you are trying to achieve, it's hard to tell the detail if any one is missing